# pip raises error Retrying

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am unable to use pip, every time I try I get this error below can anyone tell me was going on thanks.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fca90faf950>, 'Connection to 172.82.151.137 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the proxy I set as environment variable like below

```
export http_proxy='172.82.151.137:8800'
export https_proxy='172.82.151.137:8800'
```

removing this solved this issue.